# On Google Play Console, User Acquisition minus User loss does not match installed audience

Tags: google-play-console

On Google Play Console, when I count all user acquisitions minus all user losses, the result does not match what is available in the Installed Audience table. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Note: I'm already using 'all time results' on every table :/